# Can joomla and jomsocial bear 200+ concurrent user's load?

Tags: optimization, joomla, jomsocial

I have load tested basic jomsocial site (without external extensions) using JMeter for 200 concurrent users/threads.

**That causes Database connection error.**

We are already using jomsocial.
Our site has 30,000+ members. During some specific time span, site gets traffic load.
We observed that, site crashes for heavy traffic.

We will be having more online users in the future.

Few questions regarding the above scenario.

1. Is it joomla/jomsocial issue?
2. Are the joomla/jomsocial queries/code optimized?
3. How can I avoid the crashing of website?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a site with that amount of traffic, it would be best to have a VPS or Dedicated server rather that shared hosting. Using Joomla 3.0 would also be an up side as it's slightly faster than 2.5, however JomSocial isn't quite finished for Joomla 3.x. It's 98% complete: http://www.jomsocial.com/features/road-map

Comment: @Lodder we already have a dedicated server(cloud) with 4GB RAM and 8 core processor. Still we are facing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Joomla and Jomsocial offer a very high customization and are both feature rich, they will never be as optimized as a custom-written query.

That said, you should not have run into such limit yet.

**Configuration/server**
Make sure

- your database server configuration is adequate to your memory size
- you are using Joomla cache wherever possible
- you are not using any plugins / extra features which are not necessary
- you are using Jomsocial cron jobs for sending mail and maintenance and
- you did all that's documented on their site to make it faster
- you are using at least Jomsocial 2.8 as it's faster than 2.6

One last thing that will really boost your server performance is SSD drives.

**Optimize code**

Once that's done, turn on "slow query logging" in your mysql and find out which queries are the worst. Also turning on debug in the joomla frontend may give you a hint. The purpose is to find the modules / components which behave worst and manually optimize them.  It's a natural process which all large sites run into sooner or later.

Eventually when you have thousands of concurrent users you will necessarily move some tables to mongo, usually the user feeds are the first but keep an eye on your site.

Comment: 1. As I mentioned earlier, I have tested **BASIC Jomsocial** so no external plugins/extension were installed during testing. 2.Yes I am using Joomla 2.5.9 and Jomsocial 2.8.4. **Question:** If BASIC Jomsocial is having problem, all other solutions will be helpful?

Comment: you do need to find the bottleneck(s). There will be many, in your server configuration, in jomsocial and in joomla, and you spot the worst first then work your way down. Once you know your server configuration is optimal you will start looking in the code so you can achieve some results immediately. Ask your dba/ system administrator to verify the overall server load and determine what's killing it now (could be apache or mysql) and start from there.

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo Zorn. We are newbie in all this stuff. Can you provide any links to guide us for optimization?

Comment: To identify the bottlenecks, you need a system administrator with experience managing webservers: after that a programmer can look up the issues and work closely with the sysadmin to optimize and perform tests. We team up a senior developer + senior system admin in these cases, it's the most effective way; but still after all the sites we optimized, we often search the web for specific hints and optimizations (optimization is always a work in progress, and as soon as you remove one bottleneck you'll find the next). As your user base grows, if you're not optimizing it means you're scaling...